# Is it possible to have an argument for a pointer in C++ and what does that mean?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to figure out what this line of code means:

```
StJetTrack* track(int i) const { return (StJetTrack*)mTracks.At(i); }
```

So, from my basic knowledge of C++, `StJetTrack` is a class, and `track` is a pointer, but then I get confused because `track` also has an argument, which then makes `tack` a function of some sort. Does that make `track(int i)` is a function of type StJetTrack. But then what about the `*` that is usually used for a pointer. Is this a function pointer? Can someone please explain to me what I am not understanding correctly? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a function that *returns* a pointer to `StJetTrack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the syntax is:

```
return_type function_name(arguments, ...);
```

So in this case the `StJetTrack*` at the beginning means that the function return a pointer to a  `StJetTrack` object.